# Wordpress Redirect subdirectory to subdomain

Tags: redirect

We've just migrated a WPML site from example.com/fr to fr.example.com.

I'd like to keep all the link juice, so I'm trying to redirect all links that are

www.example.com/fr/mylink  ->   fr.example.com/mylink/

Here is what I have right now, but it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.:]+\.)*example\.com/fr\.?(:[0-9]*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://fr.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The site works fine still but the redirects are not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try Accessing the website via FTP and
Try adding the Code into Your wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com/wordpress');
```

This Worked for me.
Try it on your website.